# regex to match a URL with optional 'www' and protocol

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url, model-view-controller

I'm trying to write a regexp.

some background info: I am try to see if the REQUEST_URI of my website's URL contains another URL. like these:

- http://mywebsite.com/**google.com/search=xyz**

However, the url wont always contain the 'http' or the 'www'. so the pattern should also match strings like:

- http://mywebsite.com/**yahoo.org/search=xyz**
- http://mywebsite.com/**www.yahoo.org/search=xyz**
- http://mywebsite.com/**msn.co.uk'**
- http://mywebsite.com/**http://msn.co.uk'**

there are a bunch of regexps out there to match urls but none I have found do an optional match on the http and www.

i'm wondering if the pattern to match could be something  like:

> ^([a-z])*.(com|ca|org|etc)(.*)

I thought maybe another option was to perhaps just match any string that had a dot (.) in it. (as the other REQUEST_URI's in my application typically won't contain dots)

Does this make sense to anyone?
I'd really appreciate some help with this its been blocking my project for weeks.

Thanks you very much
-Tim

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest using a simple approach, essentially building on what you said, just anything with a dot in it, but working with the forward slashes too. To capture everything and not miss unusual URLs. So something like:

```
^((?:https?:\/\/)?[^./]+(?:\.[^./]+)+(?:\/.*)?)$
```

It reads as:

- optional http:// or https://
- non-dot-or-forward-slash characters
- one or more sets of a dot followed by non-dot-or-forward-slash characters
- optional forward slash and anything after it

Capturing the whole thing to the first grouping.

It would match, for example:

- `nic.uk`
- `nic.uk/`
- `http://nic.uk`
- `http://nic.uk/`
- `https://example.com/test/?a=bcd`

Verifying they are valid URLs is another story! It would also match:

- `index.php`

It would not match:

- `directory/index.php`

The minimal match is basically `something.something`, with no forward slash in it, unless it comes at least one character past the dot. So just be sure not to use that format for anything else.

Comment: Hey SuperDuperApps. Thank you so much for your help. I really like this approach. and i appreciate you explaining it all. I think i understand the syntax and logic. just what i needed and seems to be working so far.

Comment: That's great Tim, thanks. Glad to hear it's working for you.

Comment: It should be ready to work with preg_match. If you don't know how to use preg_match then I'm sure there are a lot of questions you can review to find out. Unless you have a more specific question?

Answer (score 4):

To match an optional part, you use a question mark `?`, see [Optional Items](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

For example to match an optional `www.`, capture the domain and the search term, the regular expression could be

```
(www\.)?(.+?)/search=(.+)
```

Although, the question mark in `.+?` is a non-greedy quantifier, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html.

Comment: Thanks for the useful links Olaf

Answer (score 3):

You might try starting your regex with

`^(http://)?(www\.)?`

And then the rules to match the rest of a URL.

Answer (score 2):

```
$re = '/http:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/((?:http:\/\/)?[0-9A-Za-z]+(?:-+[0-9A-Za-z]+)*(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z]+(?:-+[0-9A-Za-z]+)*)+(?:\/.*)?)/';
```

https://regex101.com/r/x6vUvp/1

Obeys the DNS rule that hyphens must be surrounded. Replace http with https? to allow https URLs as well.

According to the [list of TLDs at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) there are at least 1519 of them and it's not constant so you may want to give the domain its own capture group so it can be verified with an online API or a file listing them all.

Comment: Thanks very much AkariAkaori. This looks like a good solution.  I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my two cents :

```
$regex = "/http:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/((http:\/\/|www\.)?[a-z]*(\.org|\.co\.uk|\.com).*)/";
```

See the [working exemple](https://regex101.com/r/P9RW0S/2)

But I'm sure you can do better !

Hope it helps.