# Java Regex - multiple urls match in one output string

Tags: java, regex

I have this string:

```
jwplayer("vplayer").setup({sources:[{file:"https://v5.vidhd.net/kmxsus4zpjumwmesrlwey575ndnsv4xwfgemw6pmtbfbdks3bqofp5s6incq/v.mp4",label:"720p"},{file:"https://v5.vidhd.net/kmxsus4zpjumwmesrlwey575ndnsv4xwfgemw6pmt2xbbks3bqofaojtzsgq/v.mp4",label:"360p"}],image:"https://v5.vidhd.net/i/01/00007/vdachffyt692.jpg"
```

I want to get only the two urls i.e. the ones after `file:`.
The desired output `string` should be like:

```
https://v5.vidhd.net/kmxsus4zpjumwmesrlwey575ndnsv4xwfgemw6pmtbfbdks3bqofp5s6incq/v.mp4, https://v5.vidhd.net/kmxsus4zpjumwmesrlwey575ndnsv4xwfgemw6pmt2xbbks3bqofaojtzsgq/v.mp4
```

How can I get this in java?

### I have tried this regex: `"file:\"(.*?)\""`, but I got only the first url even that I've put `matcher.find()` inside a while loop.

Edit:
This regex works fine also the one in the @azro answer. My problem was that some code inside the while loop throws an error and stops the loop after one iteration (thanks to @pafau_k).
Sorry for the inconvenience..

Comment: hat have you tried ?

Comment: When you have a json in hand, maybe just parse json? That's one thing, the other: what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Have you at least tried [answers to similar questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044059/regex-to-match-a-url-with-optional-www-and-protocol)

Comment: I have tried this regex: "file:\"(.*?)\"" , but I got only the first url even that I've put matcher.find() inside a while loop.

Comment: That's a good regex (even better than the one in answer, because it will also find something else than https protocol). It works correctly for me, maybe post your code together with the loop (edit the question) so we can find error? Or just copy the while loop from azro's answer, that should work well.

Comment: Yiu say want URL after _file:_ but after that is in quotes ", is part of url ? url validation is that what need ? do not look like so. Try findall things `(?<=file:").*?(?=")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the urls a simple regex like this file:"(https.*?)" would work, the `*?` means a few as possible, to stop at first quote after

```
String content = "jwplayer(\"vplayer\").setup({sources:[{file:\"https://v5.vidhd.net/kmxsus4zpjumwmesrlwey575ndnsv4xwfgemw6pmtbfbdks3bqofp5s6incq/v.mp4\",label:\"720p\"},{file:\"https://v5.vidhd.net/kmxsus4zpjumwmesrlwey575ndnsv4xwfgemw6pmt2xbbks3bqofaojtzsgq/v.mp4\",label:\"360p\"}],image:\"https://v5.vidhd.net/i/01/00007/vdachffyt692.jpg\"";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("file:\"(http.*?)\"").matcher(content);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Stream version to collect at same time

```
String res = Pattern.compile("file:\"(http.*?)\"")
                    .matcher(content)
                    .results()
                    .map(r -> r.group(1))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

System.out.println(res); // https://v5.vidhd.net/kmxsus4zpjumwmesrlwey575ndnsv4xwfgemw6pmtbfbdks3bqofp5s6incq/v.mp4 https://v5.vidhd.net/kmxsus4zpjumwmesrlwey575ndnsv4xwfgemw6pmt2xbbks3bqofaojtzsgq/v.mp4
```